# How to strip/ignore unused attributes when saving a model object?

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am sending angular model objects to bookshelf to save, but it may carry extraneous attributes that aren't in the database. When I save, bookshelf will try to save all attributes and say it can't find these extra attributes.

What is the recommended way to handle this? I'm sure I can set out an array of whitelisted attributes, and strip the object manually, but is there another way?
IE, is there a built in way to ignore unused attributes? Or is there a way to query the DB to get the array of columns, then use that to strip my object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `parse()` in addition to an array of permitted attributes, like Ghost team did.

```
Mode = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  permittedAttributes: [ 'field1', 'field2', 'field3' ],

  parse: function (attrs) {
    return _.pick(attrs, this.permittedAttributes)
  }
})
```

If you define `parse()` in a base model, all models that extend it will behave the same way

Answer (score 0):

Tooting my own horn here, but I encountered this problem so many times that I created a plugin for bookshelf. Didn't want to have to manually define permitted attributes every single time.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bookshelf-strip-save